# Is it possible to get all the mysql queries called on the page?

Tags: mysql, opencart

I am using Open Cart, and it is extremely slow as I have about 3000 products. The category listing page is extremely slow, it doesn't seem like an issue with the server, I checked with various servers. I doubt that there are lots of MYSQL queries are running unnecessarily. Is there any way to get a list of all the query strings called on that page using some kind of PHP function? Or perhaps an Open Cart function?

Comment: you could also have a look at the chrome console (f12), in the audit tab you've got plenty of tools to know where the time is spent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's actually a vQmod file you can install that will create a log file for you with all of the database queries and their time taken to execute. You can find the thread and XML file [here](http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=22048#p123509)

Comment: I'm only getting the URL in the file, not the query list.Do you know what's wrong??? ( it looks like this part `public function query($sql) {` never get called... I'll also ask the developer, but mayby you know an quicker fix than through the fora ( i need it right now exactly, because the site is online now and very slow ). I've already installed you're cache module...

Answer (score 1):

You can also set `general_log` variable in mysql to ON. This will log all queries to mysql server into a file. Can be useful for debugging.